# Javascript REgExp. Need remove all words on the line from after ":" to ","

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Javascript REgExp. I want remove all words on the line after `:` to `,` 
Names of the properties must stay.
I tryed this

```
var sostavRegexp = $(".post .sostav_box").text();
sostavRegexp = sostavRegexp.replace(/:(.*),*/, ' aaaaaaa');
alert(sostavRegexp);
```

But this changed all words in line from first ":" in line to last "," in line to one word "aaaaaaa".

I have this line

> Мука: 200гр, Сахар: 200гр, Маргарин: 100гр,

Need this:

> Мука, Сахар, Маргарин

I`m designer, not a programmer. Help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the reluctant/lazy quantifier.  This will do the match between the first `,` after `:` rather than the last.

```
// g is for global replace
.replace(/:.*?,/g, ",")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is worked. but now i have some other problem. Last property don't has ",". How i can change this property too?

Мука: 200гр, Сахар: 200гр, Маргарин: 100гр, Яйца: 2шт, Какао: 2стол.ложки

Comment: @Gadunok try `(,|\.)` instead of just `,`